ReturnType of Lookup Types in TypeScript
I have a type with function fields and a utility function to get that type's function by name:
type Person = {
  getAge: () => number;
  getName: () => string;
};

function getPersonFunction<K extends keyof Person>(person: Person, key: K): Person[K] {
  return person[key];
}

Now I want another utility function to execute it dynamically:
function callPersonFunction<K extends keyof Person>(person: Person, key: K) {
  return person[key]();
}

But TypeScript infers the return type of this function as any. I tried to use ReturnType<Person[K]> to specify the return type, but it results in an error.
How can I properly call the function, infer its return type dynamically, and keep it generic?
Updated:
Additional requirements:

Filter out only methods (thanks @Alex)
Methods with input parameters


The issue arises because ReturnType in TypeScript expects a function type as its argument, but Person[K] is not necessarily inferred as a function type. You need to explicitly constrain Person[K] to ensure it is recognized as a function.

@DavidAniebo: no, my Person has function only so Person[K] is definitely function type, because I can call person[key](), the issue here is the type of returned value

TS lacks the ability to look at Person and deduce the fact that "Person[K] is a function for arbitrary K" in a way that keeps track of the return types. The supported approach, as described in ms/TS#47109, is to rewrite Person as a mapped type to explicitly express that fact, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

Hi @jcalz I think your solution addresses my question, pls write an answer & explain it, but honestly, I am also checking Alex answer which is also a good approach

Wait, you just added "advanced requirements". Are they requirements? Then [edit] your question to show it with code (you're not demonstrating input parameters or non-methods).  But why expand the scope of the question after the fact like that?

@jcalz I don't mean to expand the scope, it is just some kind of "nice to have", I just want to think about the ability to expand, so I did not update the code. I am trying to add the input parameters with your solution

"Requirements" are presumably required and not "nice to have". In any case you're expanding the scope (if you get two answers, one which covers your "nice to have"s and another which doesn't, and you choose the former over the latter, then apparently the answer to those are part of the scope of the question.) Anyway without example code provided here I'd have to come up with my own, maybe as this playground link shows. That is using the same technique from ms/TS#47109. How do you want to proceed here?

(see prev comment) Well it's now my bedtime so I'll revisit this tomorrow morning.

@jcalz I think that is the best answer, it satisfies me that: no need additional type, no cast, most similar to my original attempt that using ReturnType

The main problem here is that TypeScript lacks the ability to look at an object type like Person and verify or deduce a higher order relationship like "for arbitrary K extends keyof Person, if Person[K] is a function, then Person[K] is equivalent to (...args: Parameters<Person[K]>) => ReturnType<Person[K]>. That might seem obvious to you, but you know what Parameters<F> and ReturnType<F> mean for generic F and TypeScript doesn't. It can evaluate such types for any specific F or K, but for the arbitrary generic case, TypeScript mostly just gives up.
The solution is to refactor your types so that the relationship you care about is represented explicitly in the type, by writing them as mapped types and using generic indexes into those types. This is described in detail in microsoft/TypeScript#47109.

For your example as written, this involves refactoring Person into a mapped type over a "base" interface:
interface PersonRet {
    getAge: number;
    getName: string;
}

type Person = { [K in keyof PersonRet]: () => PersonRet[K] }

And then your callPersonFunction will just work, because its return type is inferred as PersonRet[K]:
function callPersonFunction<K extends keyof Person>(person: Person, key: K) {
    return person[key]();
}


For the general case where your functions might have input parameters and where some properties are not functions, you can write utility types to convert your type into a base parameter type and a base return type mapping:
type ParamMap<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? K : never]: 
  T[K] extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never }
type ReturnMap<T> = { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends (...args: any) => any ? K : never]: 
  T[K] extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : never }

And when you use it, you evaluate these base mapping types:
class Foo {
    a: string = ""
    b: number = 123;
    c() { return this.a }
    d(x: number) { return this.b + x }
}

type FooParams = ParamMap<Foo>
// type FooParams = { c: []; d: [x: number]; }
type FooReturn = ReturnMap<Foo>
// type FooReturn = { c: string; d: number; }

You can see that only the keys corresponding to methods are present, and the property values are the parameter list types and the return types, respectively. Now you can rewrite Foo as a mapped type that just contains the methods:
type FooMethods = { [K in keyof FooParams]:
    (...args: FooParams[K]) => FooReturn[K] };
/* type FooMethods = {
    c: () => string;
    d: (x: number) => number;
} */

The FooMethods type is a supertype of Foo, and importantly, it is explicitly represented as a mapped type over FooParams and FooReturn, so your generic calling function looks like:
function callFooFunction<K extends keyof FooParams>(
  foo: Foo, k: K, ...args: FooParams[K]
): FooReturn[K] {
    const fooMethods: FooMethods = foo;
    return fooMethods[k](...args)
}

This works because we explicitly widen foo from Foo to FooMethods. When we index into FooMethods with K we get the generic single function type (...args: FooParams[K]) => FooReturn[K], so it is callable with an argument list of type FooParams[K] and returns FooReturn[K] as desired.
Let's verify that it behaves as advertised:
callFooFunction(new Foo(), "c").toUpperCase()
callFooFunction(new Foo(), "d", 123).toFixed()

Looks good.
Playground link to code

You can use a mapped type to transform each property of, let’s say Attributes type, into a function that returns the property’s type
This creates a type Person in which each attribute becomes a method returning the corresponding value.
type Attributes = {
    age: number;
    name: string;
};

type Person = {
    [Key in keyof Attributes]: () => Attributes[Key];
};

function callPersonFun<Key extends keyof Person>(actions: Person, key: Key) {
    return actions[key]();
}

const person: Person = {
    age: () => 25,
    name: () => "Bob"
};

const age = callPersonFun(person, 'age')
const _name = callPersonFun(person, 'name')


console.log("age", age)
console.log("name", _name)

